# What is the best practice for naming list component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, naming-conventions

my React Native app show a ListView of discussions. Each ListItem will call a Discussion component.
Thus, I have two components here:
- DiscussionsList
- Discussion

Is there any best practice for naming convention on list component?
Should I rename DiscussionList in Discussions (with an 's') or any other name?

Answer (score 6):

Plural is generally used for arrays or collections if their name only contains the identifiers. ex : Discussions, Clients...

Composite name aren't pluralized. ex : DiscussionList

So, keep it simple, and use singular.